# Error creating schema table in Oracle sql

Tags: database, oracle

does anyone know why I get an error when creating a table in the qualifications scheme? I already gave you permissions to create tables

//Escuela = schema       Calificaciones = table

```
SQL> alter user Desarrollador quota 50m on system
SQL> CONN DESARROLLADOR/123

SQL> CREATE TABLE ESCUELA.CALIFICACIONES(
NOCUENTA INT,
ASIGNATURA VARCHAR(30),
CALIFICACION FLOAT,
LETRA CHAR (1),
FECHA DATE,
PROFESOR VARCHAR (30));

CREATE TABLE ESCUELA.CALIFICACIONES(
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSTEM'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, leave `system` tablespace alone, it isn't to be used by "normal" users (just as your `DESARROLLADOR` user is). Create your own tablespace, if it doesn't already exist. It *might* and its name might be `users`; check it by querying `dba_tablespaces`.

---

As of error you got:

- you assigned certain quota on tablespace `system` to user `DESARROLLADOR`
- you connected as `DESARROLLADOR`
- why are you then creating table in schema owned by user `ESCUELA`?

  - it means that `DESARROLLADOR` is granted `create any table` privilege; is there any reason for that? That user can create tables in *any* schema in the database.
- it is unclear what is `ESCUELA` allowed to do, but it seems that it doesn't have any quota on tablespace `system`